# Trying to hide a field using jQuery but it hides it after showing the original field for a few milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, performance

I am pretty much new to jQuery and have little knowledge of efficient coding. I am trying to hide a field containing "Email" and "Phone" and able to hide it perfectly but! But...it hides the field after showing the original field for a few milliseconds. What is the point of hiding a field or removing if you are able to read it somehow, right?

Here is what is happening
[image]

Note: I am trying it on my localhost and on the WordPress platform.

This is the code I am using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $(".single-at_biz_dir .atbd_contact_info ul").children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":contains('Phone')") || $(this).is(":contains('Email')")) {
            $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

I also tried to change texts using tho following code and again it shows the original text for a few milliseconds and then changes it.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".single-location .tdb_header_menu li:nth-child(1) .tdb-menu-item-text").text("Home");
});
```

Is it possible to load the page with the changes without showing the original content at all?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding display:none to the CSS style for the field. Then in jQuery you can .show() when you want to but it won't render in the initial draw. jQuery show and hide basically toggle the display css attribute.

Comment: Hiding using CSS is not a solution for me else I would have done it in the first place. I am trying to edit the single listing page and the page may have many fields depending on each post, so the nth-child of the "li" element is not the same for all the posts. :(
Thank you for the comment :)

Comment: Hm. I don't do wordpress but I bet those phone and email fields have some kind of data-id attribute that makes them different from others. If you know what that is you could put a short style tag with a specialized css selector at the top of your page to make them always display none when they load...? Just an idea.

Comment: JQuery doesn’t run until the document is loaded, so if your page is slow to load then your script won’t run immediately. The only way to prevent it appearing at all on page load is through CSS as @joshstrike suggested or on the server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments above this is because jQuery doesn’t run until the document is loaded, so the best solution here is to use CSS and target the id or class of the items you want to hide.

If you do not want to target these elements directly you can go the 'hacky' route and hide the whole unordered list using CSS. Then use your jQuery to hide the specific list items and at the end show your list again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $(".single-at_biz_dir .atbd_contact_info ul").children().each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":contains('Phone')") || $(this).is(":contains('Email')")) {
            $(this).hide();
    }
  });
  $(".single-at_biz_dir .atbd_contact_info ul").show();
});
```

Comment: A bit 'hacky' it may be, but it's a nice & easy solution especially for the OP who can't select the elements directly in CSS!

Comment: @FluffyKitten - Thanks. :) 
Aerodectyl - If this solves your issue could you mark it as resolved?